# Cannot find module app.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am starting node app.js in the server directory, and I get the following:

```
module.js:544
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'server/server/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How to fix this? It was working before, and now it's looking for a weird path /server/server instead of just /server.

I just reinstalled node to a more up-to-date version, from 5. to latest stable.

Comment: Can you specify your project directory structure and how are you starting nodmon ?

Comment: In my case, I forgot to `cd` into the current file

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you try to load your module like so:

```
require('server/server/app.js')
```

Node.js then tries to find it somewhere below `node_modules`. But I suppose, the file is not a dependency but part of your own code. Normally, you would then require it like so (consider the point at the beginning):

```
require('./server/server/app.js')
```

This makes Node.js look for the file beginning at the current directory ('.').

This would work in an environment with the following folder structure:

```
/myfiles/main.js   <-- this file contains the `require` statement
/myfiles/server/
/myfiles/server/server/
/myfiles/server/server/app.js   <-- this file is being `require`d
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with this issue because I deleted `build` folder and then try to build the project.

**Solution - in my case**

I run the `tsc --watch` that compiled all `.ts` files to `.js`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to access file app.js,

```
require('./server/server/app.js')
// to be like this
require('server/server/app.js')
```

use can using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path)

```
npm i app-module-path
```